# org.jboss.util.NotImplementedException Not able to call web service with jboss as the application server

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jboss, jbossws

I am facing a issue while calling the webservice. The exception that i am getting is shown below. I tried too many solutions available on the web like replacing the saaj jar etc but no success. Here i am using JDK 1.6.0_14 . Can java version be a problem? I am using Jboss 4.2.3.GA version.

```
10:28:01,433 ERROR [STDERR] org.jboss.util.NotImplementedException
10:28:01,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.ws.core.soap.SOAPPartImpl.appendChild(SOAPPartImpl.java:300)
10:28:01,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.xml.bind.marshaller.SAX2DOMEx.startElement(SAX2DOMEx.java:176)
10:28:01,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.TagInfoset.writeStart(TagInfoset.java:168)
10:28:01,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.xml.ws.message.stream.StreamMessage.writeTo(StreamMessage.java:447)
10:28:01,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.readAsSOAPMessage(AbstractMessageImpl.java:193)
10:28:01,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.SOAPMessageContextImpl.getMessage(SOAPMessageContextImpl.java:79)
10:28:01,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.alembik.soap.AttachmentsHandler.handleInboundMessage(AttachmentsHandler.java:104)
10:28:01,433 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.alembik.soap.AttachmentsHandler.handleMessage(AttachmentsHandler.java:94)
10:28:01,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.alembik.soap.AttachmentsHandler.handleMessage(AttachmentsHandler.java:67)
10:28:01,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor.callHandleMessage(HandlerProcessor.java:292)
10:28:01,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerProcessor.callHandlersRequest(HandlerProcessor.java:135)
10:28:01,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.ServerSOAPHandlerTube.callHandlersOnRequest(ServerSOAPHandlerTube.java:134)
10:28:01,434 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.xml.ws.handler.HandlerTube.processRequest(HandlerTube.java:116)
```

PLease help as as soon as possible as from a long time i am facing this issue but no success

Thank You

Comment: Can you add the code snippet for the implementation part, and can you specify the action which is causing this error? Wsdl is getting generated and the error is coming while calling some method right?

Comment: Have you looked at https://community.jboss.org/thread/156227

Comment: Ya i see that post. But i do not have jbossws-native-saaj.jar in my endorsed directory. I am using the alembik which uses the webservices. On my local machine the deployment is working fine but on my server machine it is causing problem. In my endorsed directory i have jboss-jaxws.jar, jboss-saaj.jar, serializer.jar, xalan.jar, xercesImpl.jar